# assign default value

Tags: java, android, exception, connection, serversocket

```
        URL test = null;
        String inputLine = null;
        BufferedReader in = null;
        try {
            test = new URL("http://localhost/out.php"); // if connection down
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            inputLine = "test_synntax";
        }
        try {
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(test.openStream()));
        ...
```

> How assign an value for inputline if by default the URL resolution has failed
>   In example context not wifi/3g connection disponible, thanks guys good day

Comment: question is unclear would you elaborate what you have to do?

Comment: and please form proper question titles.

Comment: whats worng with the way you are doing it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to call `URL.openConnection` first and then place your default value in the `IOException` block:

```
try {
   test = new URL("http://localhost/out.php");
   URLConnection urlConn = test.openConnection();
   in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConn.getInputStream()));
} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
    inputLine = "test_synntax";
} catch (IOException e) {
    inputLine = "test_synntax";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
try {
  test = new URL("http://localhost/out.php");
  //I believe you need this and it throws IOException on timeout. 
  //Though it's still unclear to me what you mean by 'resolution' and 'disponible wifi/3g`?
  test.openConnection(); 
} catch (MalformedURLException | IOException e) { 
  inputLine = "test_synntax";
}
```

This is java's 7 multi-catch syntax, mind you.

Answer (score 1):

**-** If the **wifi/3g** fails then the it will give `UnknownHostException`.

**So you can handle them like this....**

```
try {
            test = new URL("http://localhost/out.php");

        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {

            inputLine = "Connection error";
   }
```